# Pandas Group Weighted Average of Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'category':['a','a','b','b'],
... 'var1':np.random.randint(0,100,4),
... 'var2':np.random.randint(0,100,4),
... 'weights':np.random.randint(0,10,4)})
>>> df
  category  var1  var2  weights
0        a    37    36        7
1        a    47    20        1
2        b    33     7        6
3        b    16     6        8
```

I can calculate the weighted average of a 'var1' as such:

```
>>> Grouped=df.groupby('category')
>>> GetWeightAvg=lambda g: np.average(g['var1'], weights=g['weights'])
>>> Grouped.apply(GetWeightAvg)
category
a    38.250000
b    23.285714
dtype: float64
```

However I am wondering if there is a way I can write my function and apply it to my grouped object such that I can specify when applying it, which column I want to calculate for (or both). Rather than have 'var1' written into my function, I'd like to be able to specify when applying the function.

Just as I can get an unweighted average of both columns like this:

```
>>> Grouped[['var1','var2']].mean()
          var1  var2
category            
a         42.0  28.0
b         24.5   6.5
```

I'm wondering if there is a parallel way to do that with weighted averages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can apply and return both averages:

```
In [11]: g.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.average(x[["var1", "var2"]], weights=x["weights"], axis=0), ["var1", "var2"]))
Out[11]:
               var1       var2
category
a         38.250000  34.000000
b         23.285714   6.428571
```

You could write this slightly cleaner as a function:

```
In [21]: def weighted(x, cols, w="weights"):
             return pd.Series(np.average(x[cols], weights=x[w], axis=0), cols)

In [22]: g.apply(weighted, ["var1", "var2"])
Out[22]:
               var1       var2
category
a         38.250000  34.000000
b         23.285714   6.428571
```

Comment: That is helpful. However, some of my values for one column (not the others) are NaN. For those, I would like to calculate the average by dropping the NaN values and using the others. This solution instead returns NaN for those columns. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049014/python-take-weighted-average-inside-pandas-groupby-while-ignoring-nan does not treat multiple columns. np.nanmean does not allow weights. np.average does not allow options to control treatment of NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from Andy's solution, I was seeking to use one of the index levels from a multi index as my weights.

```
np.random.seed(1)
arrays = [list('AAABBB'), [0.01,0.02,0.03,0.07,0.09,0.11]]
tups = list(zip(*arrays))
x = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=x,data= np.random.randint(10,100,(6,6)),columns = list('STUVWX'))
df.index.names = ['bin','prob']

             S   T   U   V   W   X
bin prob                          
A   0.0100  47  22  82  19  85  15
    0.0200  89  74  26  11  86  81
    0.0300  16  35  60  30  28  94
B   0.0700  21  38  39  24  60  78
    0.0900  97  97  96  23  19  17
    0.1100  73  71  32  67  11  10
```

Adapting function to use one of index levels as the weights.

```
def weighted(x, w="weights"):
    return pd.Series(np.average(x, weights=x.index.get_level_values(w), axis=0),index= x.columns)
```

and calling

```
df.groupby(level=['bin']).apply(weighted,  "prob")
```

which gives:

```
          S       T       U       V       W       X
bin                                                
A   45.5000 45.8333 52.3333 21.8333 56.8333 76.5000
B   67.5185 71.1111 55.1481 41.1852 26.3704 29.9630
```