# Python calculate weighted average of multiple columns grouped by multiple columns

Tags: python, multiple-columns, pandas-groupby, weighted, weighted-average

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
State   Type Denominator    payment1 payment2   payment3
State1  A   40                  1000    8000    1000
State1  A   50                  5000    4000    5000
State1  B   70                  6000    5000    600
State1  B   30                  4000    7000    5000
State1  C   50                  1000    5000    8000
State2  A   60                  5000    7000    4000
State2  A   40                   600    5000    5000
State2  B   50                   400    6000    7000
State2  C   80                  8000    4000    1000
State2  C   40                  4000    8000    5000
State3  A   60                  5000    4000    600
State3  A   50                  7000    5000    400
State3  B   70                  5000    7000    5000
State3  B   20                  6000    4000    7000
State3  C   50                  2000    7000    1000
```

I would like to calculate weighted average for the 3 payment columns grouped by State and Type using the denominator as the weight.

On R, I would successfully use this:

```
health2=health%>%group_by(State, Type)%>%summarise(payment1mean=weighted.mean(payment1, Denominator),payment2mean=weighted.mean(payment2, Denominator),payment3mean=weighted.mean(payment3, Denominator))
```

How would I be able to  do the same on Python?

I tried something like the following but didn't work.

```
paycolumns=['payment1','payment2','payment3']

 datagrouped=data.groupby(['State','Type'],as_index=False)[paycolumns].apply(lambda x: np.average(x, weights=data.Denominator)
```

Comment: df.groupby("category") and then applying lambda function to manually do the calculation or use np.average()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33574908/6524169