# Weighted Average Multiple Columns: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks like this:

```
charge         (0.0, 1.0)   (0.0, 2.0)       (0.0, 3.0)
84          
116                 1            10                147
226                 9            842               342
343                 2            278
503                 10
939
```

I'm attempting to calculate the weighted average of each column and the post below as very helpful. [Pandas Group Weighted Average of Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574908/pandas-group-weighted-average-of-multiple-columns). So for example, column `(0.0, 1.0)`, the weighted average would be 357.54.

However, I am doing something wrong where my code produces the following error. I've done some research on this error but am still unsure how to fix it [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).

```
**CODE**: 
    def weighted(x, cols, w="weights"):
                 return pd.Series(np.average(x[cols], weights=x[w], axis=0), cols)
    
    FIN_A_PIV_Table.apply(weighted, ['(0.0, 1.0)','(0.0, 2.0)','(0.0, 3.0)']) 

**ERROR**:
        File Q:\VDI\Python Source\Provider_Coder_Updated_v_Spyder.py:372 in <module>
            FIN_A_PIV_Table.apply(weighted, ['(0.0, 1.0)','(0.0, 2.0)','(0.0, 3.0)'])
        
          File C:\Research\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8839 in apply
            op = frame_apply(
        
          File C:\Research\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:88 in frame_apply
            axis = obj._get_axis_number(axis)
    
      File C:\Research\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:550 in _get_axis_number
        return cls._AXIS_TO_AXIS_NUMBER[axis]
    
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: please provide the output of `weighted.to_dict()` for reproducibility

Comment: are your column names tuples?

Comment: @mozway sorry new to some terminology, the only output that I get when running the code I provided is the error.

Comment: @Raven what about `weighted.columns[0]`?

Comment: @mozway are you suggesting I change my code to FIN_A_PIV_Table.apply(weighted.columns[0]) ?

Comment: No sorry, I meant what is the output of `FIN_A_PIV_Table.to_dict()`, not `weighted`

Comment: {'PRO_Coder_PRO_Charge_Amount': {0: 84,
  1: 116,
  2: 226,
  3: 343,
  4: 503,
  5: 939},
 '(0.0, 0.0)': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 5.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0},
 '(0.0, 1.0)': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0},
 '(0.0, 2.0)': {0: 0.0, 1: 10.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0},
 '(0.0, 3.0)': {0: 0.0, 1: 147.0, 2: 842.0, 3: 278.0, 4: 10.0, 5: 0.0}....

Comment: And `FIN_A_PIV_Table.columns`?

Comment: Index(['PRO_Coder_PRO_Charge_Amount', '(0.0, 0.0)', '(0.0, 1.0)',
       '(0.0, 2.0)', '(0.0, 3.0)'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: So you don't have a `weights` column?

Comment: @mozway, correct the weight is the count within the  (0.0, 1.0) , (0.0, 2.0) ,  (0.0, 3.0) columns.

Comment: what do you mean by "*the count*"?

Comment: using the very top table. For example, there was 1 occurrence where a (0.0, 1.0) charge was billed for $116, there were 9 occurrences where a (0.0, 1.0) charge was billed for $226. the "count" are the number of occurrences.

Comment: Got it, let me provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weighted average is the sum of the values multiplied by the weights, divided by the sum of the weights.

You can calculate your weighted sum this way:

```
# get all columns but "charge"
df2 = df.drop(columns='charge')

# multiply the charge by the weights and sum
# divide by the sum of the weights
out = df2.mul(df['charge'], axis=0).sum().div(df2.sum())
```

Output:

```
(0.0, 1.0)    357.545455
(0.0, 2.0)    253.810619
(0.0, 3.0)    192.932515
dtype: float64
```

Comment: well you made that look easy! Do you mind commenting what the code is doing so I can better understand what's happening?

Comment: Also, how can I add column names to the two columns?

Comment: add `.rename_axis('col').reset_index(name='mean')`